# Object turns black when selecting the new image to which texture will get baked to in Blender Internal

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

There are many questions relevant to baking in **blender internal** mode. But i could not find any solution to my problem.
After creating the object I unwrapped it and *saved* the unwrapped image with a name. Next, I assigned a image texture in the texture properties panel.
Next, I selected the image texture from the drop-down menu in the UV/Image editor and the *texture is getting applied*.
Then, to bake the texture, I created a new image, and just **when I am selecting the new image, the object is turning black**. I can't proceed to bake any further. **Still it's showing that no images found to bake to**.[image: UV unwrap over the image texture.]
[image: After selecting the new image from the drop-down list.]

Comment: Can you upload the .blend? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ah yes, I uploaded the file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5039" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5039/)

Comment: textures arent saved..."File"->"External Data"->"Pack All into .blend"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Z</kbd> You will switch to "rendered shading mode" instead of "material shading mode" and will see the texture.

After you bake it, it should be viewable in material shading mode.

Your texture wasnt attached to the file, so I found a random one online [image]

Comment: Great! that works. Maybe the problem was not creating a new UV map!  I face difficulty in executing the steps one after another. : )